# Alternatives to loading core data on tabBar didSelectItem? Or speeding it up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios5, xcode4.2

I am loading core data for my TableView on didSelectItem but this makes the tabbar feel sluggish where it won't update untill the new data has loaded. What is a good way to get around this issue? Can I update the tabbar and a blank tableview before the data has loaded or could I maybe show an activity indicator somehow?

This is my current code

```
- (void) tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
NSInteger index = [item tag];
NSMutableArray *schedule = [dataHandler fetchEntriesForCourse:[[_Courses objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:@"CourseCode"]];
tableView.schedule = schedule;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you capture a menu request through the responder chain? On Mac OS X I know this is how I would do it.

Comment: Are your courses indexed?  This really shouldn't take very long under normal circumstances....

Comment: Yea, its just a second or so, but it seems like the tabs are stuck or really slow if you don't know its loading, it goes touch tab -> load data -> tab changes

Answer (score 0):

You can make your fetch in the background thread, using GCD and populate the tableview as the data comes. Here is a great article on working with Core Data in the background thread.

http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

Really, if you catch data with fetchresultscontroller, all you'll need to do is make your fetch in another thread.And then it will automaticly catch add new rows, as the fetch goes on.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making an NSMutableArray to store the data when the application is launched, thus the tabs changed faster since it didn't have to fetch the core data.